# Эквивалент var (из C#) для java

Tags: java

Насколько я понимаю, в java нельзя использовать переменные неявного типа. 
Дабы обойти это ограничение, объявил в классе 2 дополнительные переменные String (одна с типом, одна со значением, приведённым к String). У меня ощущение, что это очень кривой способ.
Есть ли что-нибудь более эффективное?

Comment: а зачем вы хотите обойти это "ограничение"?

Comment: Класс работает с sql базой данных, должен делать запрос с условиями, но какие именно будут аргументы заранее не известно.

Answer (score 7):

Я не очень понял, как ваш способ позволяет обойти это ограничение, но судя по описанию решение еще хуже, чем сама проблема. По сабжу - к сожалению **var** в java отсутствует, необходимо писать имя типа целиком

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Это не по вопросу.

В Java почти всё объект, а всё, что не объект, можно неявно привести к объектной оболочке.

```
  Object a;
  a = new String("abc");
  a = new Integer(12);
  a = new List<String>();
```

Comment: Это _не_ аналог `var`. В C# код `var x = new String("abc"); x = 5;` есть прямой аналог кода `String x = new String("abc"); x = 5;`, и поэтому не скомпилируется.

Comment: @Lapshin Dmitry ну и  что же? Искуственным приведением всех переменных к Object вы не только не решите эту задачу, но еще и создадите тысячу проблем с типизацией в рантайме и при написании кода

Comment: @VladD оу, был неправ и соглашаюсь.